# SSRS Report /SubReport / Multipe Tables or Datasets in Single Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a table Project.

```
  ProjID  Proj_task
   1       NIT 2.0  
   2       SSRS
```

I have table called  Project_Task.

```
  ProjID  Task_DS   User
   1       task1      User1
   1       task2      User2
   1       task3      User3
   2       task4      User4
   2       task5      User5
   2       task6      User6
```

I want to generate Report in Below format. (Each project ID inforamtion  shouldbe in one Page for which i am using Insert Group )

In Page 1:

```
 ProjID  : 1
 Proj_task: NIT 2.0 
 --------------------
       User       Task_DS
      User1    task1
      User2    task2
      User3    task3
```

In Page 2:

```
 ProjID  : 2
 Proj_task: SSRS    
 --------------------
       User       Task_DS
      User4    task4
      User5    task5
      User6    task6
```

I tried creating two tables, subreports, Joining two tables & creating single datasets to achive the same.
I am not able to arrive at the above mentioned format. Can Anyone please help me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat a set of items under each Project ID , you need to put sub report inside the group..

Pass the ProjectID as the Parameter to the Sub Report

So, the subreport has to run for each and every project ID . So, Create a group by PKGID and then Place that sub report inside the group so that it repeats for each Project ID

Hope this helps..If you needany furthur details..you can ask me.

Can you please provide query , for furthur details..

**Updated:**

```
Select distinct Proj_ID , Proj_name from dbo.Project
```

This should be your first data set

```
select TASK_RSLV_DS, TASK_IMPCT_DS from dbo.PROJECT left join dbo.PROJ_TASK on PROJECT.PROJ_ID = PROJ_TASK.PROJ_ID
```

This should be your second dataset

Pass the Project ID as a parameter to Subreport

**Note: You have create a group in the main report design inorder to loop your sub report.**

*for clear explanation:*

Use this link:

Here, follow the steps in creting drill down report

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD#4

Hope this helps..

Comment: select PROJECT.PROJ_ID, PROJ_NM, TASK_RSLV_DS, TASK_IMPCT_DS from dbo.PROJECT left join dbo.PROJ_TASK on PROJECT.PROJ_ID = PROJ_TASK.PROJ_ID

Comment: I put my assumption here. Pls validate it 1) I will create a subreport to display User & task Information for each Project ID. 2) Do i need to group by ProjctID in subreport as well. Or Just setting parameter is enough.

Comment: @sarvanaKumar..Please refer to the mentioed link in code project. It will clearly tell you step by step , how to create these type of reports, how to group and all. It is difficult to explain here, because it involves series of steps in design. So, thats y , i give the link to you, it would be easy for you..

Comment: @sarvanakumar..no need to group by Project Id in the sub report.Its only in the main report.

Comment: See in that example(link), how each country's details are displayed in sub report. This is exaclty same as your reqiurement. Assume that Country in the example as your Project ID..thats it.. you are done.

Comment: I don't see subreport in steps in creting drill down report topic. Is it possible for you to open chat to discuss. Thanks.

Comment: I end up with an error, after following mentioned steps. I have 32 Project ID & its task details. Task Details are associated with subreport. In first 32 pages, project details are dispayed correcty, and in 33 page, Task details are dispalyed for all the project IDs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42183/discussion-between-saravanakumarr-and-avinash)